# Alias experiment (re-adding ll to Ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, bash, files, bashrc, alias

I also use Debian 9.3 and there you don't have `ll` (lowercase LL) Out Of Box (OOB). You have to create it yourself by adding it to one of the `.rc` files (
`alias ll="ls -la"`).

In Ubuntu of course, you have it OOB, and yet, even though we have it in Ubuntu OOB, I've manually added this alias in the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc` just for the sake of experimenting in a **testing** system:

```
alias ll="ls -la"
```

I then sourced the file `source /etc/bash.bashrc` so that the change will be effective.

Is this alias duplication I did in Ubuntu (creating an alias already existing and that is already effecting my user again, in another `.rc` file) problematic in your opinion?

Having 2 identical `ll` aliases doesn't seem to do damage in testing Ubuntu in a quick look. Can it be damaging or problematic in any sense?

Edit: To make sure I'm fully clear --- I kept the original alias as well in Ubuntu, I didn't delete it. I have 2 aliases in 2 different places doing the same thing and from that I worry.

Comment: It will not hurt it will use the last of 2 or more when it cycles through the config. You might consider lA rather than la

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are free to redefine aliases as many times as you like.  There is no penalty or "danger" to the system.  Each definition overrides the previous one.  The only caution is that you might confuse yourself.

#### Example

Let's create an alias `D`:

```
$ alias D=date
$ D
Mon Jan  8 18:57:57 PST 2018
```

We can use `alias` to view the definition of `D`:

```
$ alias D
alias D='date'
```

Now, let's re-define `D`:

```
$ alias D=pwd
$ D
/tmp
$ alias D
alias D='pwd'
```

The new definition has simply replaced the old.

#### Ubuntu Initialization Sequence

When you start an interactive non-login bash shell under Ubuntu, bash will read and execute commands in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and then read and execute commands in `~/.bashrc`.

Under Ubuntu (but not Debian), the default `~/.bashrc` file contains the definition:

```
alias ll='ls -alF'
```

Since `/etc/bash.bashrc` is executed before `~/.bashrc`, any definition of `ll` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` will be overridden by the definition in `~/.bashrc`.

When starting a login shell or a non-interactive shell, the rules are different.  See `man bash` for details.

Comment: "The new definition has simply replaced the old".   That's clear, but he had put these aliases in different locations too.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Good point.  I just added a section to the answer on the two files that Debian/Ubuntu read when starting an interactive shell.